# UIScrollView with two overlapping UIImageView

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm new to objective-c and iOS development.

I need an iPad application to display some images and designs (draw) over its, but the design needs be done  in a separate image. My idea is use two overlapping `UIImageView`s, the first one is the images that I want to see, and the second one is an image with transparent background where I will draw some things with finger. All of this is OK and i have implemented, but I need that the zoom be enabled to tow images in the same time. When I'm zooming, the tow images need be resized at the same time.

The scroll needs to work to the images at the same time too.

How can I do this?

Somebody help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two `UIImageView`s you are overlapping should be subviews of the same `UIView`.

Then, apply scrolling and zooming to the base `UIView`, and it will affect also the subviews.

If you haven't added the two `UIImageView`s to a `UIView`, then you can do that like this:

```
[view addSubview:imageView1];
[view addSubview:imageView2];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I solved this problems by other way. I used tow overlapping UIScrollView. The top UIScrollView with the UIImageView to draw. Whem i scroll and zooming the top UIScrollView, a force the scroll and zooming the bottom UIScrollView.
Thank you very much again.